# PHP Math - Multiply value from database according to different ranges

Tags: php

I'm trying to multiply a value from a table in a MYSQL database inside a "formula" according to the value selected.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['valuelo'] * $row['valuear'] "</tr>";
```

Imagine,

If 0 < valuear < 50, multiply valuear per 1.5

If 51 < valuear < 100, multiply valuear per 1.2

How can I add that to my formula?
It's a normal select to a database that fetch some data from tables. 
Thanks

Comment: is $row['valuelo'] the same as 1.5, i don't get

Comment: no, thats another row from another table. i want to deal only with the value from valuear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<td>" . $row['valuelo'] * ($row['valuear'] > 0 && $row['valuear'] < 50 ? $row['valuear'] * 1.5: $row['valuear'] > 50 && $row['valuear'] < 100 ? $row['valuear'] * 1.2 : $row['valuear'] . "</td>";
```

if you want to do it in the same line or

```
$value = (($row['valuear'] > 0 && $row['valuear'] < 50) ? $row['valuear'] *  1.5 : (($row['valuear'] > 50 && $row['valuear'] < 100) ? $row['valuear'] * 1.2 : $row['valuear']));
echo "<td>" . $row['valuelo'] * $value . "</td>";
```

to be more clean.

Comment: I guess this will work! let me run some tests and I'll get back to you!

Comment: Only the last condition is working! I used the clean version! No matter which values I get from table. It always multiplies with the last condition (1.2 in this case)

Comment: @Hween I forgot the parenthesis, my bad

Comment: I was wondering, Why do you end with? : $row['valuear']))); I can read the code but it doesnt make sense to me that final part! (just for knowledge lol). It works great1

Comment: it's the default case, if no condition is true then we have to use this variable, if you put anything else here, it will be the default case so you could define any other variable to affect at $value if all is false

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if(($row['valuear'] > 0) && ($row['valuear'] < 50)){

     $value = $row['valuear'] * 1.5;

 } elseif(($row['valuear'] > 51) && ($row['valuear'] < 100)) {

     $value = $row['valuear'] * 1.2;

 }
```

Comment: Hey man! Tried and works also! I used the other one because its easier to add more conditions! Thank you